# Distributed TensorFlow with in-memory data

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I need to randomly generate synthetic in-memory data (in the form of pandas DataFrames) to be fed to a TensorFlow Estimator that is distributed on multiple parameter servers and workers. How can I achieve that? Which server should be in charge of generating the data and how do I pass them to the others? Would something along these lines work?

```
def main(_):
    ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
    worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")
    #Create a cluster from the parameter server and worker hosts.
    cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": ps_hosts, "worker": worker_hosts})
    #Create and start a server for the local task.
    server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name=FLAGS.job_name, task_index=FLAGS.task_index)

    if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
        server.join()
    elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":
        if FLAGS.task_index==0:
            train_data, train_labels = generate_synthetic_data()
            eval_data, eval_labels = generate_synthetic_data()
            test_data, test_labels  = generate_synthetic_data()

    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter( worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index, cluster=cluster)):

        # Run training
        train_and_evaluate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]])
```

Or, similarly, here
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/linear#overview they create two pandas dataframes that are then fed to the Estimator. How would that code be parallelised?

Answer (score 0):

TF Estimators do not currently easily support a single shared input pipeline. Instead each worker has its own independent input pipeline, to maximize throughput.

So generate a separate synthetic dataframe in each worker.